# Array of numbers vs Object type in Typegoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, typegoose

I'm fairly new to Typegoose. I have created a class with a field that should have an array of numbers such as:

```
class A {
  ... some other properties ...

  @prop({ required: true })
  public nums!: number[];
}
```

Following is the sample code to populate a new object:

```
let field = {};
field.nums= {1,2,3};
a = new A(field);
```

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I create a new object of the class, instead of saving **{1,2,3}** in the **nums** field, the program is saving it as **{{1},{2},{3}}**. However, when I change the type of **nums** from *number[]* to *Object*, the values are stored as desired.

P.S. I also tried changing type of **nums** from *number[]* to *Array* and still faced the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem thanks to an [issue](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/300) posted on typegoose github repo. According to the post, while working with property of *array* types, another property is required in *@prop* decorator that identifies the type of objects in an array. Following is the updated sample code:

```
class A {
  ... some other properties ...

  @prop({ required: true, type: [Number] })
  public nums!: number[];
}
```